# Controlling the Soft Keyboard during onClick - Android

Tags: android, button, onclick, android-softkeyboard

I had an issue where if user was typing and hit submit, the keyboard would not go away, so I found this code to fix that issue (by placing this in the onClick method):

```
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

However, if the user manually closed the keyboard, then clicked submit, I found the code above would bring the keyboard *back* -- not good.

The question:

Is there better code to use? OR can I just say something like =

```
 if (keyboard = displayed) {
            // do code above
          } else { 
            // do nothing 
          }
```

Comment: Although I don't know the answer to your question, make sure to change that if(keyboard = displayed) into -- if(keyboard == displayed)  Just preventing future errors.  :)

Comment: ah, of course.  I think I would have gotten that but good call!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To hide the keyboard:

```
final InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =
            (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

To show it:

```
final InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =
            (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

Comment: Showing the keyboard did not work for me on Android 6.0.1!